# Use a package to install dependency and copy custom conf file

Tags: debian, make, packaging

I used `dh_make` to create a basic Debian package install. I added a dependency which is the actual program I want. All I want to do is overwrite the `conf` file this package installed, with a new file with bunch of custom parameters.

I tried to use the `install` file which looks like this:

```
file.conf /etc/destination/file.conf
```

but repeatedly got an error saying:

```
dh_install: cp -a debian/tmp/file.conf debian/custom-package//etc/package// returned exit code 1
```

I can't figure out why it won't find the file. I know `debian/tmp` is created by the builder, but I don't know why it won't find my file, then it tries to copy not to the directory I want, but it prepends `debian/custom-package/`.

I also tried to use a Makefile but while it builds and runs, the file isn't copying to the directory. I'm not sure the Makefile is right or is even getting called (`dh_make` didn't originally include a Makefile, I'm not sure where to call it if it doesn't get called).

The make file just has the install directive and looks like this:

```
install:
        cp file.conf /etc/destination/
```

The rules file is the basic file that was built with `dh`, and as recommended from the Debian guide:

```
%:
        dh $@
```

Comment: In `file.conf /etc/destination/file.conf`, what is destination? And what is the exact name of your install file? pkgname.install will try to install in `debian/tmp/pkgname/etc/destination/`, I think. You don't want both an install file as well as an install rule in make. They both do the same thing - copy stuff to the files under `debian/tmp` which packages are made from. You probably just want a line in an install file.

Comment: Oh, and include your rules file, please. You should probably also be using `dh`.

Comment: The rules file is the recommended file from the debian guide, very short, I added it above. I am trying the solution posed by @Stephen Kitt, basically deleting the install file and only using the directive in the Makefile.

Comment: Your package doesn't sound complicated. I suggest you put the whole thing somewhere public, if you can't figure it out. And post a link here, of course.

Comment: I will try and do this later, can't right this minute. I am sure the solution is very close, but I'm just missing some small component. And you are right, it is a very simple package.

Comment: The problem as I was approaching it was actually kind of unsolvable. Even if I had solved my initial problem, there was a larger issue with automating the process and overwriting files belonging to another package (like conf files). I found a better solution and posted it to this thread. Thanks fo you help everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by using a package called `config-package-dev`.

[config-package-dev link](https://debathena.mit.edu/config-packages/)

While I didn't realize it at the time, there was a big flaw in what I was trying to do previously. Updates or changes to the package could have overwritten my custom `.conf` files on update and the system would have been broken.

`config-package-dev` solved this issue by making symlinks to my custom `.conf` files, which insulates the configuration to changes (among other things). In addition it accomplished all the things I was trying to do and made the entire process much cleaner. I ended up throwing away my old solution and making an entirely new package with the debian package building tools.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

See [the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/ConfigPackages) for detailed instructions to create a configuration package. The short version given what you've already got is:

- delete the `install` file
- in your `Makefile`, specify the `install` target as follows:

```
install:
        mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)/etc/destination/
        cp file.conf $(DESTDIR)/etc/destination/
```

- in your `debian/rules`, just run `dh`:

```
%:
        dh $@
```

Comment: Is `$(DESTDIR)` something I need to set manually or is it inherited somewhere? I made these changes and while it had a noticeable effect in that the make process was much less verbose, the `.conf` file is still not the one I included in my package, nor did I get any errors regarding files not being found or any such thing.

Comment: The above comment is not quite right, lintian did return an error stating: `unknown-file-in-debian-source file.conf`

Comment: `DESTDIR` is defined by the build tools. Where is your `file.conf`? The lintian error means it's in `debian/source`, it should be in your package's main directory.

Comment: So I am still seeing the basic `.conf` file when I install. I moved the file out and don't get any lintian errors but I am also not seeing my modified `.conf` file anywhere. Do I need to add the file to `conffile`? I have read that this is not the best practice. I also read that conf files can be placed in `etc/` within the build package, but no where is clear on where in the build package the mean. I also tried adding `-f` to the `cp` in my Makefile but that did not seem to have any effect either.